# Mean calculation worst case, best case and average case complexity

Tags: complexity-theory, pseudocode, mean

What is the (a) worst case, (b) best case, and (c) average case complexity of the following function which calculates the mean

```
n=0
sum=0
input(x)
while x!=-999 do
    n=n+1
    sum=sum+x
    input(x)
end {while}
mean=sum/n
```

How would you justify the complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stop as soon as `-999` is found.

Therefore:

- the best case is O(1) : you find -999 directly
- the worst case is O(n) -n being the size of `input`-: you find `-999` at the very end of `input`
- the average case is in that case O(n / 2) = O(n): you find `-999` in the middle